# Count two columns where another column is unique

Tags: sql, count

I am looking for a way to get a count of the number of times a combination of values occur across two columns, but only where the value hasn't already been counted for that id.

For example a table containing 5 rows:

```
Table name = person
someid | firstname | surname
1        John        Doe
1        John        Doe
1        Johnny      Doe
2        John        Doe
3        Johnny      Doe
```

I would like to get the following results:

```
firstname | surname | count
John        Doe       2
Johnny      Doe       2
```

I have tried group a few combinations of count and group by without success. What are the key aspects that I am missing here?

Cheers

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does "where the value hasn't already been counted for that id" really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, use `GROUP BY` clause and aggregate function `count` to get desired result which outputs one row per your group counting all the rows.

```
select firstname, surname, count(distinct someid) as count
from person
group by firstname, surname
```

Since you only need to account unique ids use `distinct` clause within the aggregation.

Comment: Whag if there is a column like 4,John,Doe. In other words another John Doe with a different ID

Comment: _"but only where the value hasn't already been counted for that id."_. That doesn't fit into OP requirement.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I missed the distinct clause in the aggregation.